# cursor color - smooth transition between diferent backgrounds

Tags: css, sass, mix-blend-mode

On a website I'm creating there is a cursor that needs to change its color smoothly.
When it is on a white background the cursor needs to be the blue `#0059ff` (this is important and I will explain why later on) and when it is on blue then the cursor needs to be white; and the transition needs to be smooth like so:
[image: Two concentric circles over a corner of a white-ish polygon where the word "kontakt" is being written. The two concentric circles are white-ish where over the background, and blue where over the polygon]

To get the white color with `mix-blend-mode` I'm calculating the inverted color using `adjust-hue($color, 180)` (in SCSS) and applying this color to the cursor.
When the background color is `#0000ff` then cursor should be `#ffff00`.

I have started a prototype using `mix-blend-mode: difference` that works on "primary colors" (basically colors like `#ff0000`, `#ff00ff` and so on).
Result:
[image: The text "Hover me" on white over a blue background with the white double circles "cursor" on the right, completely white]
[image: The same "Hover me" text, this time in blue over the "cursor", now bigger and still white]

Problems begin when I try to change the "primary" blue `#0000ff` to the one needed by the project `#0059ff`. The inverted color is calculated to be `#ffa600` and the result is, let's say, "unsatisfactory" because I want the cursor to be white on some background color and said color on white background.
[image: Same image as before with the cursor on the right, but now the cursor is purple]
[image: The "Hover Me" text is over the bigger purple "cursor", written in blue.]

Calculating the difference will not work with this color and I have no idea how to make it so that when the cursor is not over the white background then the cursor becomes blue (-ish) and when it's over the blue background it becomes white.

My whole code so far:
(SCSS compiled so it can run in StackSnippet)

```js
const bigBall = document.querySelector('.cursor-ball-big');
const smallBall = document.querySelector('.cursor-ball-small');
const allHoverable = document.querySelectorAll('a, .hoverable');

TweenMax.to(bigBall, .3, {fill: 'none'});

allHoverable.forEach(hoverable => {
    hoverable.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        TweenMax.to(bigBall, .3, {scale: 4});
        TweenMax.to(bigBall.querySelector('circle'), .3, {strokeWidth: 1});
    });
    hoverable.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        TweenMax.to(bigBall, .3, {scale: 1});
        TweenMax.to(bigBall.querySelector('circle'), .3, {strokeWidth: 2});
    });
});

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const {clientX, clientY} = e;

    TweenMax.to(smallBall, .1, {x: clientX - 5, y: clientY - 7});
    TweenMax.to(bigBall, .4, {x: clientX - 15, y: clientY - 17});
});
```

```css
:root {
  --color1: #0059FF;
  --color2: #FFFFFF;
  --cursor: #ffa600;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.cursor {
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.cursor .cursor-ball {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.cursor .cursor-ball.cursor-ball-small circle {
  fill: var(--cursor);
}
.cursor .cursor-ball.cursor-ball-big circle {
  stroke: var(--cursor);
}

a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: none;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  background-color: var(--color1);
}
.left a {
  border-color: var(--color2);
}
.left h1,
.left p,
.left a {
  color: var(--color2);
}

.right {
  background-color: var(--color2);
}
.right a {
  border-color: var(--color1);
}
.right h1,
.right p,
.right a {
  color: var(--color1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
    <div class="cursor-ball cursor-ball-big">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="30" width="30">
            <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="12" stroke-width="2"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="cursor-ball cursor-ball-small">
        <svg height="10" width="10">
            <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="left">
    <a href="#" title="Hover me">Hover me</a>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <a href="#" title="Hover me">Hover me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you don't define your color in javascript?
Disable mix-blend-mode and give color to cursor by javascript when hover.

Comment: @Saeed.Modarresi Well. That would work only if I don't need transition like on first screenshot. Only part that overlays, in this example button, should change color.

Comment: Set transition by default in style. And then change the color by js. I'll try to write complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea how to make it so that when the cursor is not over the white background then the cursor becomes blue (-ish) and when it's over the blue background it becomes white.

In this case, the mix-blend mode is very limiting. When you want to have completely unrelated colors then it's not possible to use it.

However, I am able to achieve the desired effect using [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

```js
const allHoverable = document.querySelectorAll('a, .hoverable');
  const sBall = document.querySelector('#ball1 > circle');
  const bBall = document.querySelector('#ball1 > text');
  const sBall2 = document.querySelector('#ball2 > circle');
  const bBall2 = document.querySelector('#ball2 > text');

  allHoverable.forEach(hoverable => {
    hoverable.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      TweenMax.to(bBall, .3, { fontSize: 100, xPercent: -24, yPercent: 12 });
      TweenMax.to(bBall2, .3, { fontSize: 100, xPercent: -24, yPercent: 12 });
    });
    hoverable.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      TweenMax.to(bBall, .3, { fontSize: 50, xPercent: 0, yPercent: 0 });
      TweenMax.to(bBall2, .3, { fontSize: 50, xPercent: 0, yPercent: 0 });
    });
  });

  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;
    TweenMax.to(sBall, .1, { x: clientX - 5, y: clientY - 7 });
    TweenMax.to(bBall, .4, { x: clientX - 25, y: clientY + 10 });
    TweenMax.to(sBall2, .1, { x: clientX - 5 - window.innerWidth / 2, y: clientY - 7 });
    TweenMax.to(bBall2, .4, { x: clientX - 25 - window.innerWidth / 2, y: clientY + 10 });
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --color1: #0059FF;
  --color2: #FFFFFF;
  --cursor: #ffa600;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: monospace;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: none;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left2,
.right2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* left */

.left {
  background: var(--color1);
}

.left a {
  border-color: var(--color2);
}

.left h1,
.left p,
.left a {
  color: var(--color2);
}


/* left2 */

.left2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: url(#ball1);
  background: var(--color2);
}

.left2 a {
  border-color: var(--color1);
}

.left2 h1,
.left2 p,
.left2 a {
  color: var(--color1);
}


/* right */

.right {
  background-color: var(--color2);
}

.right a {
  border-color: var(--color1);
}

.right h1,
.right p,
.right a {
  color: var(--color1);
}


/* right2 */

.right2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  clip-path: url(#ball2);
  background-color: var(--color1);
}

.right2 a {
  border-color: var(--color2);
}

.right2 h1,
.right2 p,
.right2 a {
  color: var(--color2);
}

.bBall {
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 1000;
}


/* for debugging delete later */
a {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: -2px;

   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;

   -webkit-user-drag: none;
   -khtml-user-drag: none;
   -moz-user-drag: none;
   -o-user-drag: none;
   user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Slab:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="left">
  <a href="#" title="Hover me">Hob</a>
</div>
<div class="left2">
  <a href="#" title="Hover me">Hob</a>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <a href="#" title="Hover me">Hob</a>
</div>
<div class="right2">
  <a href="#" title="Hover me">Hob</a>
</div>

<svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="ball1">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" stroke-width="0" />
        <text x="0" y="0" class="bBall">O</text>
      </clipPath>

      <clipPath id="ball2">
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" stroke-width="0" />
        <text x="0" y="0" class="bBall">O</text>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
```

I've tested the output on `Chrome 97 on Windows 10`.
In case the required font is not available, here is how it looks:
[image]

---

**Explanation**

- I created element `left2` which is exactly same in dimensions as `left`. Except colors are inverted. Background is white and text is blue.
- `left2` superimposes `left` exactly.
- added `clip-path` `#ball1`(small ball) to `left2`.
- The `#ball1` clips `left2` leaving left exposed, except the small area of `left2` below it.
- For outer ring(big ball), there is no way to have hollow clip path. So I used font with perfect circular letter '**O**' in the svg.  And onHover I am just increasing the font size to make it big.
- Repeated the same steps for the right side. Created `right2` etc...
- Clip path is relative to the container, so you'll see two cursors for each side at the same time. So had to create duplicate clipPath `ball2` for the right side and shifted it to left by 50vw. So it remains below mouse pointer.

Comment: That's a good answer as it does what I'm trying to get, but duplicating content is unacceptable because google. Positioning will kill this site. Nevertheless, if no other answer comes up, I will accept yours and confess to defeat.

Comment: How positioning will kill the site? and what is wrong with duplicating content? Can you elaborate.

Comment: By positioning I mean that it may dissapear fro search results. I have experienced it before and it is not consistent. Page dissapeared from search results because of duplicated content. Sometime google labels website with duplicated content as "attempting to manipulate search engine rankings or win more traffic." (not explicity) and therefore lowers said site position or removes it from search engine.

Comment: Ohh I see! Good to know thanks! But this is a legitimate case, like, if you are demonstrating 10 fonts on your website with same text for comparison. There has to be a way to tell/appeal google search engine that we are doing it for genuine reasons. 